# Setting role access_controll symfony 2

Tags: symfony, roles, access-control

I have some problems with `access_controll.`

```
    role_hierarchy:
          ROLE_ADMIN:  [ROLE_USER]

 - {path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
 - {path: ^/pag1, roles: ROLE_USER}
 - {path: ^/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN}
```

This is my security.yml

I presume that with this settings a `Role_user` can see only `login` and `pag1`, and the `role_admin` can see all the pages (`path: ^/` match with all that not match with `login` and `pag1`, right?).

In my project with `role_admin` I can't see any other page, and I don't know why.

Comment: With role_admin, are you getting not authorized 403 error?

Comment: yes, i'm getting access denied with forbidden 403